# Git - The Remote Repository Rejected Commits

Tags: xcode, github

I created a new branch manually from Xcode, which for some reason did not show up on the repository, so I made another branch from the GitHub browser manually. Then when trying to commit I'm met with the error:

"The remote repository rejected commit. Make sure you have permission to push to the remote repository and try again."

I've talked to my boss who ensured that I'm given written permission, so we're both confused as to why I can't commit properly.

Comment: Are your user.name and user.email the same as the ones that are beeing verified on the remote? 
You can check by typing `git config -l`

Answer (score 23):

[image]

If you have this option selected in the [Email Settings](https://github.com/settings/emails) page of GitHub it will prevent you from pushing.

Comment: Awesome, possum. This fixed it for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6758725/faisal-syed please accept this answer so that other users can also benefit from it.

Comment: You may want to use "git config -l" to review the email that your git client is sharing and possibly update it with "git config --global -e"

Comment: Thank you my friend, I would never have figured it out on my own! It's in the Settings -> Email section, way at the bottom.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go in to terminal, and then go to your project directory and type these commands.

```
xcrun git config user.name "your username here"
xcrun git config user.email youremail@somedomain.com
```

Make sure the user name and emails are the exact ones that you use on github, gitlab etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was using "Personal Access Token" for authentication and was facing the same issue. For some reason, generating a new token and entering it again in Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts fixed it.